Running custom GRASS script under QGIS on Mac
I have a GRASS GIS script that I would like to run from QGIS. I followed the instructions reported here so I created a script.qgm file and added it into the /grass/modules directory, I put the script under the /grass/scripts directory and modified the default.qgc to ideally add the script to the modules' tree but it didn't work.
I am on QGIS 3.38, and GRASS GIS 78 (from g.version, inside QGIS) on MacOS Sequoia.
